# Solution Folder can't be checked into TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

A solution created with VS2010 with solution folder. When checking into this solution to TFS, the solution folders are missed on TFS.

How to sync TFS and VS2010 with solution folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution folders only exist within a solution file, not on disk. They are purely a visual organization tool.

If you check in the solution file and have someone else get it and open it, they will see the folders just as you see them.

Answer (score 0):

They are not missing only on TFS but on your local disk as well. Solution folders are different than physical folders and TFS tracks only files and physical folders. So you could create the corresponding physical folder (manually outside Visual Studio) and add the files to this physical folder.